# Extract This Field From Json Array PHP

Tags: php, json

Hi guys I have been working with a JSON array that is returned via api.

```
[ 
{ "Id": "81654bdf-f56d-4e0e-ad3a-57860ad5be24", 
"Name": "TESCO PLC", 
"Address": { "StreetNumber": null, 
         "StreetName": "TESCO HOUSE SHIRE PARK", 
         "PostCode": "AL7 1GA", 
         "City": "WELWYN GARDEN CITY", 
         "StateCode": "AL", 
         "CountryCode": "GB" }, 
"PhoneNumber": "44-1992632222", 
"LegalFormCode": "PLC", 
"ExternalIds": [ { "ExternalId": "1057587", "ExternalService": "eulerid" },
             { "ExternalId": "00445790", "ExternalService": "CRO" }, 
             { "ExternalId": "216854067", "ExternalService": "DUN" }, 
             { "ExternalId": "2189357501", "ExternalService": "HRM" }, 
             { "ExternalId": "220430231", "ExternalService": "TVAGB" }, 
             { "ExternalId": "345370", "ExternalService": "ACI" }, 
             { "ExternalId": "376445", "ExternalService": "HCIS" }, 
             { "ExternalId": "38", "ExternalService": "GROUP" }, 
             { "ExternalId": "432577", "ExternalService": "PNCH" }, 
             { "ExternalId": "5594389", "ExternalService": "SIACID" }, 
             { "ExternalId": "574064", "ExternalService": "EHIPNR" }, 
             { "ExternalId": "7013000615", "ExternalService": "EURODB" }, 
             { "ExternalId": "FE0181198", "ExternalService": "SFACID" }, 
             { "ExternalId": "G14788", "ExternalService": "KMV" } ] },
```

To extract the Street NameI used :
   $buyerStreetName=$row['Address']['StreetName'];

How ever I am now trying to capture the eulerid and don't know how I can do this as it does not have a unique field name so I need to get the ExternalId where the ExternalService = eulerid

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to used `json_decode()` and loop the result set just like any regular array. JSON does not make this special in the slightest bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This ought to do the trick:

```
<?php

foreach ($row['ExternalIds'] as $val)
{
    if ($val['ExternalService'] == 'eulerid') {
         $externalId = $val['ExternalId'];
    }
}
```

Comment: glad i could help! :-D

Comment: @MikeDray please mark this question as Answered so delboy gets the credit (Not that he needs it at 4000+) but it does show up on searches.

Comment: sorry I was waiting. He answered it so fast it told me I had to wait 4 mins before I could accept his answer

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use `array_column()` to create an associative array of the data to make access easier, so the code comes down to...

```
foreach ( $data as $row )   {
    $externalIds = $row["ExternalIds"];
    $externalIds = array_column($externalIds, "ExternalId", "ExternalService");
    echo $externalIds["eulerid"];
}
```

( the outer `foreach()` is probably something you already have, just here for completeness)